# Post Update Git Hook On Local Machine Not Executing

Tags: bash, git, ubuntu, githooks

I have an Ubuntu server that runs a production build. Every time I push to the main branch, I want my Ubuntu to pull and run some commands. I created a file called "post-update" in <repo-root>/.git/hooks. In there, I wrote a simple command:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "POST-UPDATE" >> post-update.log
```

Nothing happens when I push to the main branch. The log is empty no matter what I try. This seems like a simple problem but I have been at it for 4 hours now, I've got to be missing something.

I tried editing the permissions of the log file.

I tried changing ownership of the repo.

I tried running the script itself and it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: `post-update` is a server-side hook, it doesn't run locally. It runs on the server where you push to.

Comment: It's just `update`, but yes, it's a server-side hook.

Comment: @phd Any idea how I would achieve my goal? Would I have to put something on the remote repo and have it ping the server to tell it to update?

Comment: Push from local to two remotes; use git alias, shell alias, shell function, shell script to automate.

Comment: If you control the remote, then you can use a `post-receive` hook on the remote to run a script after it (successfully) receives a push. If you don't control the remote, then you might be able to use a webhook from the remote provider; the details on that will depend on the provider.

Comment: It'd help if you'd explain what you want the hook to actually do. Are you trying to ping a third system? you push, remote accepts, third system gets notified?  That's usually done in a post-receive on the remote, but you could do it locally by just checking the `git push` exit code. `git push && notify-server`.

Comment: @jthill I'm trying to run "npm run build" "conda env update -f {filename}.yml" and restart apache to account for changes.